# jQuery location.reload() is not executed inside my ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, reload

I have defined the following JavaScript inside my ASP.NET MVC application:

```
function reloadpage() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval("location.reload(true)", 60000);
    });
}
```

I call the above JavaScript inside my view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/reloadpage.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, the web page does not reload after 1 minute. What might I be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function 'reloadpage' in the file reloadpage.js is not invoked anywhere, then loading will not work.

Try below code in the file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval("location.reload(true)", 60000);
});
```

Or

```
function reloadpage(min) { 
   setInterval("location.reload(true)", min*1000);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    reloadpage(60);
});
```